# Interactions of forces and tensions between several bodies connected in series, such as on a train

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A train of 10 wagons each having a mass of $4 \times 10^4 kg$. Locomotive has a mass of $2.2 \times 10^5 kg$ and pulls the first wagon with a force of $8\times10^5 N$. What is the tension between the first and the second wagon?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: thanks to gandalf61 for pointing out my mistake in neglecting friction.

**TL;DR**
By drawing free body diagrams (FBD), it is clear that each wagon pulls all other wagons behind it. So the force $F$ equals 10 times the uniform friction force, and the tension between wagon 1 and 2 is 9 times the friction force. See the FBD below.

**Full answer**

In such questions, it is **imperative** to draw free body diagrams indicating all external forces. Assuming that the train drives in a straight horizontal direction, say to the left, with the locomotive to the left of wagon 1, we have:

[image: Free body diagrams]

where

- $F = 8 \times 10^5N$ is the pull the locomotive exerts on the 1st wagon,
- $T_i$ is the tension of wagon $i$,
- $m = 4 \times 10^4 kg$ is the mass of each wagon,
- $f$ is the friction force,
- $g$ is the gravitational acceleration at Earth's surface,
- $W = mg$ is the weight of each wagon and
- $N$ is the normal force.
  Since all wagons have the same mass, and we are assuming no other forces are present, $N = W = mg$ for each wagon.

For simplicity only 4 wagons were drawn. Here we are assuming that the train is moving at constant velocity. A similar analysis can be done if the train had a non-zero acceleration, but not enough information is given in the question to solve this. Thus the sum of forces on the train as a whole as well as on each wagon individually must equal zero. Also, we are assuming that the couplings between each wagon are rigid and non-deformable. This means that although no data is given explicitly that would enable us to directly calculate the friction force, it nevertheless **must** be considered. Finally, since each wagon has an equal mass, we can assume that the friction force opposing the movement of each wagon is the same.

Now this question is interesting because it illustrates how forces/tensions increase when objects are attached in series.

Let's first consider wagon 10 on the right. The friction force $f$ is proportional to the normal force and therefore to the mass. By summing the forces in the horizontal direction, we see that $T_{10} = f$. Now let's move on to wagon 9. By Newton's 3rd law, $T_{10}$ has an equal but opposite reaction acting on wagon 9. This wagon is being pulled by tension $T_9 = T_{10} + f = 2f$. This process can be done repeatedly for all wagons.

It is now clear that the tension pulling a wagon increases as we move further toward the locomotive. Every wagon to the left must not only overcome its own friction, but must also pull the other wagons behind it.

So to answer the question, the first wagon pulls all nine other wagons, and must also overcome its own friction. Thus $F = T_1 + f = 10f$ so $f = 8 \times 10^4N$. Now for wagon 2, $$T_2 = 9f = 7.2 \times 10^5N$$

Note that if the train was accelerating, each tension would be higher than the previous one by a larger term for each wagon.

An analogous phenomenon is that of 2 climbers climbing on a single rope, one higher than the other. The rope must support the weight of both climbers, and each of them must support only their own weight. Now imagine that the rope is cut in half such that the highest climber holds on to the upper half, and the lower half of the rope is attached to the waist of the higher climber. The lower climber holds on this lower half. The upper rope still holds the same total weight, however the higher climber must now support the weights of both climbers. Here it is unnecessary to take friction or drag into account, because we are considering the weight, which is additive. But in the train problem, we *must* consider a horizontal force proportional to the weight of each wagon (friction).

Comment: You are assuming there is no friction. But if this were the case then the last wagon has an unbalanced force $T$ acting on it, and so is accelerating while the other wagons are not. This is inconsistent with the assumption of rigid couplings. I think a better assumption is that there is an equal friction force $F$ on each wagon, and by considering all of the wagons together we can see that $T=10F$.

Comment: @gandalf61 You are entirely correct. It was a huge late-night blunder on my part. I will edit my answer to reflect your point.